# Как оформить блок с кодом?

Tags: html, css

Сам я еще новичек в вебе, пришла идея создать сайт(не важно что там будет), где будут вставки с кодом, вот пример того, что я сделал:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но дело в том, что хоть это(как мне кажется) выглядет еще более менее, то вот код оставляет желать лучшего(ничего остроумнее я не придумал кроме как просто создать по одному`<span>` для каждого цвета в синтаксисе и как вы понимаете выглядет это абсолютно нечитабельно(вот пример, таже показывать стыдно такой код)):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел бы узнать нет ли более разумного решения для того чтобы оформить блок с кодом?!

Comment: Хм, а разве нет библиотек для подсветки синтаксиса? А если нет, может взять и написать?

Comment: UPD: https://highlightjs.org/ вам в помощь

Comment: Я пока ```js``` не изучаю, разбираюсь пока с ```html``` & ```css```, хотел узнать как это можно сделать именно с помощью этого. Про ```js``` - библиотеку возьму на заметку, как начну изучать его, разузнаю про это. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: #Z1FiR, эту библиотеку нужно просто подключить, далее она сама, js для нее учит не нужно

Comment: Будут вопросы по подключению - пишите в комментарии. Новичок может запутаться в том, как подключать библиотеки, но в реальности ничего сложного нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то для этого используется тег `<code>`.

Вот простой пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег CODE</title>
 </head>  
 <body> 

  <p>Код программы</p>
  <p><code>
    function checkParent (src, dest) {<Br>
     while (src != null) {<Br>
       if (src.tagName == dest) return src<Br>
        src = src.parentElement<Br>
     }<Br>
     return null<Br>
    }</code></p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Подробнее [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/code).

Ну а что касается цвета, то это только через `css`, либо как вариант поискать сайт, который позволяет сразу же преобразовать подсветку синтаксиса в соответствии с нужным вам ЯП и выводит это в готовые `html` и `css`.

Comment: Поискал сайты, которые длают подсветку, ничего лучше того, что я придумал там не увидлел(там так же для каждого цвета свой ```span```), но все же это по крайней мере облегчает работу, не надо по пол часа сидеть спаны эти вставлять, сайт сам все сделает!) Благодарю за помощь!